# Error al crear formulario en Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario, en la cual este es mi index.html y main.gs

Lo que estoy tratando de crear es un formulario que permita almacenar información que se registre en una hoja de cálculo que se encuentra en Google Sheet, pero resulta que no me permite almacenar, lo que busco es usar esta hoja de cálculo como una base de datos en la cual puedan ingresar información.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<script>
function procesaFormulario(){
   google.script.run.procesaFormDatosPersona(document.forms[0]);
}
  $(function() {
    $( "#guardar" ).click(procesaFormulario);
  });
</script>

<html>
<?
  var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1r5UJJZcPL64JAmqyz8p1cV_e6m7QtlHT040pThF7QWw");
  var hojaParametros = hojaParametros.getSheetByName('Parametros');

  var ultimaFila=hojaParametros.getLastRow();
?>
<div>
<form id="datosPersona" name="datosPersona">
 <br>
 Nombre (s):
 <br><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="primer y/o segundo nombre" required>

 <br>
 Apellido (s):
 <br><input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="primer y/o segundo apellido" required>

 <br>
 ID:
 <br><input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Numeros y Letras" required>

 <br> Sexo:
 <br>
 <select type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo" required>
 <? i=2;
   while(i<=ultimaFila){
 ?> <option value="<?=hojaParametros.getRange(i,1).getValue()?>"><?=hojaParametros.getRange(i,1).getValue()?></option>
 <?  i++; }  ?>
 </select>
 <br><br>
  <button class="action" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 </html>
```

**MAIN.GS**

```
// Llamar al HTML

 function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(!e.parameter.page){
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
  }  
  var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page);
  template.action=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
   //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
 function procesaFormDatosPersona(e){
   var sNombre = e.nombre;
   var sApellido = e.apellido;
   var sId = e.id;
   var sSexo = e.sexo;  
   var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1r5UJJZcPL64JAmqyz8p1cV_e6m7QtlHT040pThF7QWw");
   var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Datos');
   var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,1).setValue(sNombre);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,2).setValue(sApellido);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,3).setValue(sId);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,4).setValue(sSexo);  
 }
```

pero resulta que al momento de publicar el formulario, me muestra este error:

> TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getSheetByName" de undefined. (línea 6, archivo "Main", proyecto "informacion 2019")

¿Qué podría modificar en mi código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en

```
var hojaParametros = hojaParametros.getSheetByName('Parametros');
```

Muy probablemente se resuelva (depende de que  `SpreadsheetApp.openById("1r5UJJZcPL64JAmqyz8p1cV_e6m7QtlHT040pThF7QWw")` devuelva un objeto `Spreadsheet`) cambiado dicha línea por

```
var hojaParametros = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Parametros');
```

Consejo: En lugar de incluir sentencias de código "complejas" entre `<?` y `?>` declara funciones en archivos `.gs` y llama estas entre los `<?` y `?>` de tal forma que sea más sencillo realizar la depuración del código usando el editor de Google Apps Script, más específicamente, podrías llamar la función a depurar desde el selector de funciones del editor de Google Apps Script.

Comment: si, justamente eso era, habia puesto hojParametros pero era hojaCalculo

Comment: tengo una consulta mas, espero me pueda ayudar,gracias. este es el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287539/problemas-al-acceder-a-mi-formulario-en-google-sheets