# Problemas al acceder a mi formulario en google sheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

actualmente he creado un formulario que que permita almacenar información que se registre en una hoja de cálculo que se encuentra en Google Sheet.  este es su codigo

index.html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<script>
  function procesaFormulario(){
    google.script.run.procesaFormDatosPersona(document.forms[0]); }

  function getNombres(nombres){
    var txtNombres = document.getElementById("nombre");
    txtNombres.value = nombres;
  }

  function getApellidos(apellidos){ $("#apellido").val(apellidos);}

  function getSexo(sexo){ $("#sexo").val(sexo).change(); }

  $(function() {  $( "#guardar" ).click(procesaFormulario); });

 function preventFormSubmit() {
   var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
 }   
}
 window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
</script>
<html>
   <head> <base target="_top"> </head>
<?
  var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1B2Mvx3yrKE4PvVoG7FZt8ajt-7NoCXOuKCQkGquNl_k");
   var hojaParametros = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Parametros');  
 var ultimaFila=hojaParametros.getLastRow();
?>
<center> <div> <form id="datosPersona" name="datosPersona">
 <br>
 Nombre (s): <br><input type="text" style="width:300px" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="primer y/o segundo nombre" required>
  <br>
  Apellido (s): <br><input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="primer y/o segundo apellido" required>
  <br>
  DNI: <br><input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Numeros..." required>
  <br>
  Sexo: <br>
  <select type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo" required>
  <? i=2;
     while(i<=ultimaFila){
  ?> <option value="<?=hojaParametros.getRange(i,1).getValue()?>"><?=hojaParametros.getRange(i,1).getValue()?></option>
  <?  i++; } ?>
 </select>

<br><br>
   <button class="action" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
 </form> </div> </center>
 </html>
```

y el gs es el siguiente:

Código.gs

```
  // Llamar al HTML

  function doGet(e) {
      Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
      if(!e.parameter.page){
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
      }

   var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page)
   template.action=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
   return template.evaluate();
  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
 }
 function procesaFormDatosPersona(e){
    var sNombre = e.nombre;
   var sApellido = e.apellido;
   var sId = e.id;
   var sSexo = e.sexo;  
   var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1B2Mvx3yrKE4PvVoG7FZt8ajt-7NoCXOuKCQkGquNl_k");
   var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Datos');
   var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,1).setValue(sNombre);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,2).setValue(sApellido);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,3).setValue(sId);
   hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFila+1,4).setValue(sSexo);

 }
 function getNombresSS(e){ var sId = e.id; return  buscaEnSheet(sId, 1); }
 function getApellidosSS(e){ var sId = e.id; return  buscaEnSheet(sId, 2); }
 function getSexoSS(e){ var sId = e.id; return  buscaEnSheet(sId, 4); }
```

cuando yo ingreso al formulario, el cual es este link:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzkfMLukIz5YTHwg6lyEVi0G97hAxMERavf3Bq5Qvoo_6rlmbEw/exec

me muestra el formulario normal, y se guarda informacion normal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando otra persona intenta ingresar desde su laptop o pc, les aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para publicar doy los permisos de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema está relacionado con la configuración de la aplicación web de Google Apps Script.

Tienes dos parámetros relacionados con permisos

1. "Ejecutar como" que se refiere a cuales permisos debe usar la aplicación, los del usuario que la ejecuta  o los del propietario de la aplicación
2. Quien puede ejecutar la aplicación

(imagen tomada del la referencia indicada más abajo)

[image]

En el parámetro 1 asegúrate de especificar que se ejecute con los permisos del propietario de la aplicación

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: acabo de añadir a mi consulta una imagen, y creo que esta bien porque estoy habilitando para que todos puedan ingresar

Comment: @Kevincs7 Que bueno que agregaste la captura. No está bien porque está que se ejecute como el usuario que accede la aplicación. Haz clic en ese selector y escoge la otra opción.