# ¿Es posible publicar una web app de google sin que pida iniciar sesión cuando un usuario público intenta acceder a ella?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Tengo un script asociado a una google spreadsheet, la cual recoge datos de varias hojas de cálculo y las incrusta en un html.

La idea es publicar eso como una web app de google, utilizando su editor de comandos y su consola de proyectos.

Todo funciona bien y va sin problema pero pide loguearse a cualquier usuario que intente acceder al link, cuando necesito que sea público, es decir que no pida iniciar sesión, he probado publicándolo dándole acceso a cualquier usuario pero sigue pidiendo el loggin, ¿se os ocurre alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Sí es posible, para ello, además de configurar que cualquiera puede acceder a la aplicación,  debes seleccionar que se va a ejecutar con tus privilegios.

En "Execute the app as:" debes seleccionar "Me" seguido de tu dirección de correlo electrónico.

En "Who has access to the app" debes seleccionar "Cualquier usuario"

[image: Publicar como aplicación web]

Relacionado

- [Problemas al acceder a mi formulario en google sheets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/287539/65)

Answer (score 0):

Si, la poción que tienes es de una comunicación server to server, es decir cualquiera podría realizar peticiones sin autenticación. para lograr eso es mejor trabajar con credenciales del tipo account services.[link crear cuentas de servicio](https://support.google.com/workspacemigrate/answer/10839762?hl=en)